# How to implement a functionality to enable users suggest edits in an item of a custom list?

Tags: workflow, custom-list, custom-form

I have intermediate experience in Sharepoint. I have a custom list with about 20 fields.

I want to create a functionality for end users where they can suggest edits in an existing item. It should work as follows:

- When users modify an item, an additional draft item should be created which should be sent to the admin for verification.
- If the admin verifies it, the original item will be updated with the new values.
- Until the draft item is accepted, the item should maintain its original values.

Is it possible in Sharepoint? with Workflows?

Comment: So...did my answer work?

Comment: @Tally thanks for your answer.. actually our team opted for another solution in which the end user can directly suggest changes thru the presentation page itself.. we set the page's html as contenteditable. The user can make the modifications, and click on Done which will send the admin an email with the contents of the page. We thought this approach will be user friendly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could enable content types via the List Settings>Advanced Settings.  Then in List Settings>Versioning Settings - set it to YES.

Regarding "Until the draft item is accepted, the item should maintain its original values" - this can be configured in Versioning Settings>Draft Item Security.

The overall process you are describing is an [approval process](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/require-approval-of-items-in-a-site-list-or-library-cd0761c4-8c3f-4ea2-9435-13c28aa23d08).